# rmr2 mapreduce always generate NULL for $key and $val

Tags: r, hadoop, cloudera

I installed rmr2 in R with Cloudera Quickstart 5.7.0 as per [Jeremy](http://jeremy.kiwi.nz/2015/07/23/hadoop.html) and [Chandra](https://www.r-bloggers.com/integration-of-r-rstudio-and-hadoop-in-a-virtualbox-cloudera-demo-vm-on-mac-os-x/).  I tried a simple mapreduce program as per [Chandra]:

```
small.ints <- to.dfs(1:1000)
out <- mapreduce(input = small.ints, map = function(k, v) keyval(v, v^2))
df <- as.data.frame(from.dfs(out))
```

and the output of df is:

```
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

and from.dfs(out) shows:

```
$key
NULL

$val
NULL
```

Other examples from  [Jeremy] and [Chandra] are also producing the same output although mapreduce shows _SUCCESS in the generated /tmp directory.  Any suggestions?

to.dfs and from.dfs seem to be working fine.  I tried:

```
small.ints <- to.dfs(1:1000)
out <- from.dfs(small.ints)
out
```

and this produces the numbers from 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out now.  I installed rmr2 from within RStudio and somehow the library was not available to the script even though the mapreduce function seems to run successfully.  I was surprised that in one of the logs, I read that rmr2 was not found, but the script still gave me a _SUCCESS!

I eventually installed rmr2 fresh in R (using sudo R), with the required packages, reshape2 and caTools, and everything seems to work fine now.